# Qt: Access functions of class which is using a GUI widget outside the constructor

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a Qt-GUI called "mainWindow".

In the constructor I am using a class called "testclass", which uses a widget from the GUI.

```
mainWindow::mainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
testclass window_test(ui.Widget);
window_test.function();
}
```

Now I would like to access functions of "window_test" outside of the constructor.

I tried to add

```
testclass window_test(ui.Widget);
```

as a class member to the mainWindow class but I can't access ui.Widget there.

Whats the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the prototypes of your functions in the header file of your mainWindow? It may simply be a scope issue.

Comment: I have .h/.cpp files for the "mainWindow" class and for the "testclass".

I generated an instance of "testclass" in the "mainWindow" constructor. But now I can only access functions of "testclass" in the constructor, but I want to acess them also in button callback functions etc.

Comment: Add that instance under private in your `mainWindow.h` , this should make it available throughout your mainWindow.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

I added the instance of "testclass" to mainWindow.h but I had to use a standard constructor for it. Therefore I declared a new function to pass the widget to the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass a parameter to the constructor of your member variable `window_test`, you can do it like this:

```
mainWindow::mainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
  window_test(ui.Widget)
{
}
```

The declaration of the member variable is simply

```
class mainWindow {
  ...
  testwindow window_test;
};
```

If `ui` is itself a member variable of `mainWindow` which has a constructor, the order of declaration can be important. `ui` should then be declared before `window_test` so it is already constructed when it's used.